# How to read service broker queue using SqlDependency?

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker, sqldependency

```
public void StartDependency(){    
 _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GSMIntegrationDatabase"].ConnectionString;

queueName = "RequestQueue";

SqlDependency.Start(_connectionString, queueName);    
}     



  public void RegisterDependency()
    {             
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            string queries = "Select SourceFieldName, DestFieldName from Integration.tblMap;" +
                            "Select ShortName, LongName, ObjName from Integration.tblSystem";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queries, connection);

            //Monitor the Service Broker, and get notified if there is change in the query result
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command, "Service=ReceiveNotificationService;local database=GSMRevamp", Int32.MaxValue);

            //Fire event when message is arrived
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             throw ex;
        }            
    }
```

this method methods register data with Onchange Method

```
    void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var info = e.Info;
            var source = e.Source;
            var type = e.Type;

            Console.WriteLine("Onchange executed");

            SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;

            dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            RegisterDependency(); //Re-register dependency is required after a notification is received everytime


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }                           
    }
```

By using this code I can monitor queue.
I want to get the data from service broker queue using SqlDependency.
whenever there is any data push into queue in database immediately SqlDependency OnChange Should be triggered.
But I Didn't got solution anywhere.

Comment: Not at all? This is about the worst way to try to deal with a broker queue - given that there is specific SQL to wait for incoming messages. And that a change in the table does not necessarily mean you want to read a message. Back to learning the basics.

Comment: As above. Also note that [you cannot even read from the internal tables that back the SB queues without using a Dedicated Administrative Connection](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/09/dealing-with-large-queues/)